# How do I access embedded resources in Visual Studios using Visual C#?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I've seen tons of other posts about this and they make no sense. This is the structure I saw from another post.

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "MyCompany.MyProduct.MyFile.txt";

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I don't understand what goes in the `"MyCompany.MyProduct.MyFile.txt"` part. Is it "WindowsFormApplication2.Properties.Resources.LabelData.txt"? Because that is not working. I keep getting a NullReferenceException... I'm assuming its from not having the right file. Here's the code I have as it stands.

```
public void readAllLabelValues()
        {

            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var resourceName = "WindowsFormsApplication2.WindowsFormsApplication2.LabelData.txt";

            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))

            using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                foreach (Label label in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Label>())
                {
                    label.Text = (Reader.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: make sure that you've changed in the properties of the text file the build action to be Embedded Resource and not the default Content value.

Comment: Select the file in solution explorer in VS, then goto properties window and do as described above

Comment: please mark (and vote) the answers that helped you to solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that you can use Application.StartUpPath for this. This is the code I used to make a valid path to it:

```
string fileLocation = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "programData.txt");

            if (!File.Exists(fileLocation))
            {
                File.Create(fileLocation);
            }
```

Then to read and write to it, just create the StreamReader or StreamWriter pointing to fileLocation.

Answer (score 0):

you can see in the microsoft site (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292) that the naming convention is:

> The compiler adds the root namespace of the project to the name of
>   the resource when it is included in the project. For example, if the
>   root namespace of your project is MyNamespace, the resources are named
>   MyNamespace.MyTextFile.txt and MyNamespace.MyImage.bmp.

you can use the debugger to find out what is the resource name by using the following code:

```
thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string [] resources = thisExe.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

if you don't see it in the resources make sure that you've changed in the properties of the text file the build action to be Embedded Resource and not the default Content value.

Comment: How do I get it to print it out so I can see the name?

Comment: foreach(var name in resources) Console.WriteLine(name);

Comment: So is it LabelData.LabelData.txt?

Comment: it should be the nameSpace as a prefix followed by .LabelData.txt
if your nameSpace is LabelData then yes but it's probably your project name which is the default nameSpace

Answer (score 0):

```
WindowsFormApplication2.LabelData.txt
```

Comment: When I ran the thing that told me all the namespaces I got WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Resources.resources for one of them. Its not throwing a null exception but how do I specify the LabelData.txt file?